# Blog Pagination Not showing in my custom template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I created a custom blog template in my WPLMS Wordpress theme, with wp-query. But I'm unable to show the pagination. I tried to build a shortcode its working fine but in the last im unable to show my pagination.

//blog section 2

add_shortcode('da-blog', 'da_blog_post');

function da_blog_post($attr, $content = null){

```
$attributes = extract( shortcode_atts(array(

'title'     => 'blog post',
'subtitle'  => 'latest news',

), $attr) );

ob_start(); ?>

<section class="exthree_blog">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="all_exthree_blogs">
                    <div class="row">


                    <?php 
                        $blogcontent = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'posts_per_page' => 6,
                        'category__not_in' => array( 75 ) 
                        ));
                    ?>

                    <?php while($blogcontent->have_posts()) : $blogcontent->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="single_exthree_blog">
                                <div class="exthree_box">
                                    <div class="exthree_box_img">
                                        <!-- <a href=""><img src="img/shutterstock_770159185.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a> -->
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
                                            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID())){ ?>
                                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),'medium'); ?>
                                            <?php }else{
                                                $image = vibe_get_option('default_course_avatar');
                                                ?>
                                                    <img src="<?php echo vibe_sanitizer($image,'url'); ?>" />
                                                <?php
                                                } 
                                            $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name' );
                                            ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="exthree_box_fortag">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="boxxx">
                                        <div class="exthree_box_title">
                                            <h4><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="exthree_box_categor_list">
                                            <?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="exthree_box_desc">
                                            <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="exthree_box_button">
                                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Continue<img src="http://localhost/gostudent/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Layer-2.png"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php  echo "helooooooooooooooo"; ?>
                    <?php $big   = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                    $links = paginate_links(array(
                        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                        'total' => $next_the_query->max_num_pages,
                        "type" => "list"
                    ));
                    echo $links; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>    

<?php return ob_get_clean();

wp_reset_postdata();
```

}

Comment: Also right now im working on Localhost